# Only one PanGesture can be called a time

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

For example, I have multiple buttons with multiple pangestures like this

```
   let buttonGes: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonPanGesture(recognizer:)))
   button.addGestureRecognizer(buttonGes)
```

My problem is that while I'm dragging a button and try to drag another one at the same time, my logic will not working properly. Therefore, I want to limit only 1 pangesture can be called at a time, how do I do that?

Update: I tried a method that at `state .began`, I make other buttons `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and re-enable at `state .ended`. It worked fine but I don't know if it would be the most optimized code or there is better methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this job, you should use [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate) for better clarity

Comment: Tried that and used `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` with a `check` variable. Solved most of my problem but there is one thing that is still there, double pan at the same time (not one after other).